# ArityException when generating an array

Tags: clojure

So I have this piece of code here, which generates an array like so:

```
(gen_array 10 3) -> [10 10 10] (puts 3 10's into array)
(gen_array "Hello" 3) -> ["Hello" "Hello" "Hello"]
```

But it doesn't work, and returns an `ArityException` on `thread "main"`.

Here is a more detailed error:

```
Exception in thread "main" clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (2) passed to: PersistentVector
```

Here is the code:

```clojure
(ns test.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn gen_array [n times]
  ((def out []) (for [x (range times)] (conj out n)) out))

(defn -main []
  (println (gen_array 10 3)))
```

Comment: Don't `def` in your function.  And if you really really must, you have to use a `(do (def ...))` here (or leave the () around your function body, since defn implies a `do`).  otherwise you are just calling the result of `(def out [])` (which gives you the error).

Comment: just use `repeat` instead: `(defn gen-array [n times] (into [] (repeat times n)))`

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some conceptual clojure's semantics and style misunderstandings:

first of all the actual error is caused by your attempt to call what is returned by `(def out [])` as a function. Since it returns a vector, it is totally ok to call it as a function, if you pass it an index as a param, but here you pass two arguments, namely `(for [x (range times)] (conj out n))`  and `out`, so it ends up with an arity exception.

second: even if you will rewrite it to

```
(defn gen_array [n times] 
  (def out []) 
  (for ...))
```

or (which is a correct way to introduce the binding)

```
(defn gen_array [n times]
  (let [out []]
    (for [x (range times)] (conj out n))
    out))
```

it would still fail to add to `out`, since clojure's data is immutable, and `for` is lazy, so you would be getting empty lists as a result all the time:

```
user> (gen_array :x 10)
;; []
```

the correct way to fulfill this task with `for` is:

```
user> (defn gen-array [n times]
        (vec (for [_ (range times)] n)))
;; #'user/gen-array

user> (gen-array :x 10)
;; [:x :x :x :x :x :x :x :x :x :x]
```

but the simplest is:

```
user> (defn gen-array [n times]
        (vec (repeat times n)))
;; #'user/gen-array

user> (gen-array :x 10)
;; [:x :x :x :x :x :x :x :x :x :x]
```

Comment: leetwinski gave the right answer here but just in addition if you want to accumulate data on a structure with conj, reduce or (for specific taks) loop/recur are the functions you need, for is more like a map

Comment: Thanks! So what exactly does `vec` do? Also, don't I declare a variable using `(def name [])` (so now `name` is an empty array)? What do you mean by a function in that sense?

Comment: `vec` converts the collection to [vector](http://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Vectors) . The second is about immutability: you define the var and set it to be `[]`, but you can't just "put"a value there. When you use `conj` it returns a new vector based on the `[]` with added value, but the old vector isn't changed. here is a nice intro: http://www.braveclojure.com/do-things/

Comment: the vector (as map, and set) have the feature of being a also a function. this means that they implement `IFn` interface and can be called as a function: `([1 2 3] 1)` => 2 (getting an element by index), and `def` returns defined value, so: `((def x [1 2 3]) 1)` => 2

Answer (score 0):

Leetwinski has already answered well but I would like to add some more things and explain the problem differently.

I think you missed the point because you programmed like in Java or similar language.

**First error : the definition of the initial collection**

In Clojure, `def` creates a global variable (in the context of your namespace) which will exist also outside your function.
But here, the accumulator you define just needs to exist inside your function like in a class method (a namespace is a class, a function is a subclass of it after compilation).

For this purpose, the right way to do is to use `let`, then your object `out` exists only in the context of your `let` :

```
(let [a 2]
  ...do a lot of thing with your local a...
 ) ;; after that, you cannot call a anymore
```

**Second error : out is not mutable**

Clojure standard objects are not mutable, `i.e.` when you do (f value) with f as a function, you creates implicitely a new object and value itself is not changed :

```
(def value 2)
(inc value)
value ;; 2
```

So even if you did :

```
(defn gen_array [n times]
  (let [out []]
    (for [x (range times)] (conj out n))))

(gen_array 2 2)
```

You would have returned `([2] [2])`

**Third error : you thought that for was the same for as the Java one**

For in Clojure is used to create a collection by iterating over input collection as the last example shows you. In fact, when you use `for` with a single collection, it is equivalent to `map`.

Here, you can use `for` of course but what you had initialy in mind (accumulating values inside a vector) is achieved by using `reduce` or `loop/recur` which are closer to the Java loop than `for` and `map` which iterates over an existing collection to transform values (it is so like an Iterator). `doseq` and `dotimes` can be used.

**Various solutions**

I will rewrite the solutions given above (of course `repeat` is the best) but here are some solutions to show you how to implement what you had in mind (Java style) :

```
;; Note that many of these pieces of code are not idiomatic, just for fun

;; Reduce implementation
(defn gen_array [n times]
  (reduce
    (fn [agg n]
      (conj agg n))
    [] (range times))) ;; out is []


;; Uses transitory transient collection
(defn gen_array [n times]
  (persitent!
    (reduce
      (fn [agg n]
        (conj! agg n))
      (transient []) (range times))))

;; Uses an atom, which is mutable

(defn gen_array [n times]
  (let [agg (atom [])
        _ (dotimes [_ times] (swap! agg conj n))]
    @agg))

;; Loop/recur version

(defn gen_array [n times]
  (loop [out []
         i 0]
    (if (= times i)
        out
        (recur (conj out n) (inc i)))))

;; Real Java Object[] assuming you want to pass any Object !

(defn gen_array [n times]
  (let [out (object-array n)]
    (amap out idx ret n)))
```

Comment: Yeah... I came over here from Python and JavaScript, so it was different. Thanks for this answer!